# How to create subclass from parent in python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, parent-child

I am trying to create an easyAI subclass which inherits from the parent Player class. The code works fine with each class standalone but seeing as they're so similar in style I thought it best to make all 3 AI difficulties inherited.

I have tried inheriting the class like `class subClass(parentClass)` but this returns a NameError that parentClass is not defined.

```py
    class Player:
        def __init__(self,stack,UID):
            self.stack=stack
            self.UID=UID
            self.pocketCards=[]
class EasyAI(Player):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spotted the problem . rather embarrassingly was an indented block in another area of code .

Answer (score 0):

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self,stack,UID):
        self.stack=stack
        self.UID=UID
        self.pocketCards=[]
```

Comment: Hi, this still threw the Name error for player not defined.

Comment: the classes are in same python file?

Comment: yep. they follow each other like in the original post